# django models timer delete

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to put a timer on each object that is created
after the time is up the object will delete itself

I have my models set up so far I can see if I create an object and I can see my Gamesplayed object with all the data on HTML

is there a way to add another field to the Gamesplayed of a countdown timer that will be shown on HTML and will delete the objects after the time is up?

my models

```
from django.db import models

class Gamesplayed(models.Model):
   Game=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
   Myviews = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
   Price=models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

is there any field that dose that? saw Durationfield but not sure how to use

Comment: You might write [Django's Custom management Command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) and check the condition infinitely

Answer (score 0):

The deletion on browser side could be done using javascript code. On backend side i think you don't need to delete anything, just add some [`DateTimeField`](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField), call it `expire_time` and when providing data to page select only what has `expire_time > NOW()`